# Combine two textbox value into other textbox in lowercase with dash

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have two text type inputs. I want to convert them into one textbox(Lowercase with dash)  while typing just like below.

```
<input type="text" name="first">
<input type="text" name="last">
```

I want combine this two text box into another textbox

Example: `Nikhil Patel` to `nikhil-patel`

I am trying to combine below inputs but can't.

```js
function conv(){

                var title, author;
                title = document.getElementById("title").value;
                author = document.getElementById("author").value;

                /*converting to LowerCase*/
                title = String.toLowerCase(title);
                author = String.toLowerCase(author);

                var out  = title + "-" + author;

                document.getElementById("output").value = output;
            }
```

```html
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title :</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Author :</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="author" id="author" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Output :</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="output" id="output"/>
    </div>
```

Output is not printing automatically

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, welcome to stack overflow, to help us to better answer your question can you let us know what you've tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try This if you want like this...

```js
var input = $('[name="first"],[name="last"]'),
    input1 = $('[name="first"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="last"]'),
    input3 = $('[name="final"]');
input.change(function () {
    input3.val(input1.val() + ' - ' + input2.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="first" id="1" value="">
<input type="text" name="last" id="2" value="">
<input type="text" name="final" id="3" value="" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>  
  <SCRIPT>
            function conv(){

                var first, second;
                first = document.getElementById("first").value;
                second = document.getElementById("second").value;

                /*converting to LowerCase*/
                first = String.toLowerCase(first);
                second = String.toLowerCase(second);

                var out  = first + "-" + second;

                document.getElementById("out").value = out;
            }

        </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
    <BODY>

        <input type="text" name = "first"  id="first" onkeyup = 'conv()'/>
        <input type="text" name = "second" id ="second" onkeyup = 'conv()'/>
        <input type="text" name = "out" id="out"/>      
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

1. this is just a sample with 3 text boxes where
   first two boxes will be for input
   and third will auto populate using the javascript
   I hope it'll help you. All is did was to add extra id's.